# Registering types with StructureMap via Scan method

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have `IService` interface and many IService implementations in other assembly. I need to register all implementations as service for types that are in inheritance chain between IService and concrete IService implementation. 
For example:

```
public interface IService{}
public abstract class BaseService<T>: IService{}
```

And in another assembly:

```
public class SomeSpecialService: BaseService<SomeType>{}
public class AnotherSpecialService: BaseService<AnotherType>{}
```

So, I need register `SomeSpecialService` as service for `BaseService<SomeType>` and `AnotherSpecialService` as service for `BaseService<AnotherType>`.

Currently, I do this via reflection with registering each implementation one by one.

1) Is it possible using the Scan() Expression?

2) Is it possible using the Scan() Expression if SomeSpecialService is internal (non-public) class in another assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
        var container = new Container(
            c => c.Scan(
                s =>
                    {
                        s.TheCallingAssembly();
                        s.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(BaseService<>));
                    }));
```

If you have multiple implementations of `BaseService<>` for concrete generic argument (e.g. `BaseService<SomeType>`) you need to name registrations and resolve them by name.

```
        var container = new Container(
            c => c.Scan(
                s =>
                    {
                        s.TheCallingAssembly();
                        s.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(BaseService<>)).NameBy(t => t.Name);
                    }));

        var service = container.GetInstance<BaseService<SomeType>>("BaseServiceForSomeType");
```

When you have only one implementation per generic argument and you need to have other than default lifecycle (Transient) then you can use `s.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(BaseService<>)).OnAddedPluginTypes(c => c.Singleton());`

When you need even more customisation while registering types then you can define you registration convention.

```
        public class BaseServiceConvention : IRegistrationConvention
        {
            public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
            {
                if (!type.IsConcrete())
                {
                    return;
                }

                var interfaceTypes = type.FindInterfacesThatClose(typeof(BaseService<>));

                foreach (var closedGenericType in interfaceTypes)
                {
                    if (GenericsPluginGraph.CanBeCast(closedGenericType, type))
                    {
                        registry.For(closedGenericType).Singleton().Use(type).Named(type.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And you apply this convention like this:

```
        var container = new Container(
                c => c.Scan(
                    s =>
                        {
                            s.TheCallingAssembly();
                            s.Convention<BaseServiceConvention>();
                        }));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what about registering internal types from another assembly?

Comment: @Albert sadly I can't think of a way to auto-register internal types. I don;t think it is possible so you will have to make the types you need to register public (if it is possible).